# Display c++ code in php

Tags: php, c++

I am trying to display the contents of a .cpp file in php. I am loading it using fread when I print it out it comes out formatted incorrectly. How can I keep the format without escaping each character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

echo "<pre><code>";
$filename = "./test.cpp";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // assuming max line len is 4096.
        echo htmlspecialchars($buffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo "</code></pre>";

?>
```

We need htmlspecialchars function to print it out correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to look at it in a web browser:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)); ?>
    </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Note that it's wise to escape special characters like `<`, `>` and `&`.

Answer (score 2):

print it out between the HTML `<pre>` & `<code>` tags.

Comment: This is what I needed. But how do I get it to display The #include <stdio.h> correctly?

Comment: all it displays is #include and then skips the <stdio.h> part

Comment: <pre>#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;</pre>